# (extremly simple) debugging Groovy scripts running embedded

Tags: groovy, jvm

Please give me some guidance, link to read: how to perform basic debugging of Groovy script running in bigger Java application.

I'm not totally green, I had to use debugging API in Python 1.x (old time, old :) ) and Lua, both from C/native environments.

I can imagine:

- jump to hosting code (machine) on exceptions
- dump variables (I've attended in some threads here - maybe it isn't
  simply)
- set breakpointI would be happy.

Be most beautiful debugger in the world is not required. 
Please give track for future reading.

Comment: Did you try a normal Java debugger? Because normally those work. After all Groovy generates Java classes even for simple scripts

Comment: To tell the true, I'v never used java debugger from SDK  :) Assume we we understand each other: all work is out of IDE. Can You send entry point of documentation?

Comment: Try the community edition of IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: A broader context would probably be helpful, are you running your application as a standalone jar? In a web application container? Something even more exotic, like a midlet? Anyway, debugging groovy is... quite the same as debugging the Java application itself, at least in Intellij IDEA. When you work _out of IDE_, the normal course of action is to run your application in a debug mode, which opens a so-called JDWP port, to which you then connect with your IDE.

Comment: Thans for advice. I have new idea, maybe totally stupid: because many Java classes (String, Collections etc) are "decorated" in Groovy, maybe execution is "decorated" too, in other words Groovy build kind of "wrapper" over calling methods by specific aspect programming / bytecode manipulation? G. has such JARs in depedencies.

Comment: Thanks Michal. I understand (in general, as a user) connecting debugger to port. I'm not sure in production environment port are technically (firewalling etc) or at organisational level (agreement with client admin, chief ) available to me ... I'm thinking maybe wrong kind of wrapping "in JVM" (to keep hands on pulse)